# Circular Structure error .postJSON data

Tags: javascript, json, typeerror

```
 var selectFormula = $(htmlContainer).find("ins").map(function (i, el) {
        return {
        fName: $(el).attr("data-record-name"),
        fID: $(el).attr("data-record-id"),
        fContent: $(el).text()
      }
        //fContent: $(htmlContainer).each(function () { if (!$(this).text().trim().length) { $(this).remove(); } }),
      });
//keep
      //var selFormInner = $(htmlContainer).find("ins").map(function (i, el) { return {
      //  fName: $(htmlContainer).find("ins[data-record-name]"),
      //  fID: $(htmlContainer).find("ins[data-record-id]"), 
      //  fContent: $(htmlContainer).find("ins").each(function () { if (!$(this).text().trim().length) { $(this).remove(); } })
      //}
      //}); //inner content  (array)
      if (selectFormula /*&& selFormInner.length*/) {
        // Get formula HTML from server
        $.postJSON(formulaUrl, {
          //name: selFormName.map(function () {
          //  return $(this).data('record-name');
          //}).toArray(),

          ////return information on the corresponding record id
          //recordID: selFormID.map(function () {
          //  return $(this).data('record-id');
          //}).toArray(),

          //return infmoration on the corresponding content of ins.
          //formula: selFormInner.map(function () {
          //  return $(this);
          //}).toArray()
          formula: selectFormula  };
```

This is a part of my script file(all javascript) that is requesting to execute a server-side method with the shorthand $.postJSON. I keep running into this "Converting circular structure to JSON" It happens on this line:  'data': JSON.stringify(data) in the included postJSON script file.

My question is specifically focused on the on the circular structure. This could be wrong, but I think it highly likely that it is referring to my variable selectFormula declared at the top. What is circular about this structure? I have done some reading with people getting the same error but their examples seemed more obvious than mine, an object referring to itself etc.

This JSON data that i am passing to the server has a struct created in a similar manner in c# but that doesn't really matter since it doesn't hit my server side method, this error is all client side. As you can see with lots of my commented out code, I have tried quite a few things. All of them wrong of course!

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, converting the structure to an array here stopped the Circular Structure error. Jquery's: .toArray() method. Then All I had to do was edit my server side method argument to match. Thanks anyway if anyone tried to work on this!